# Predicate in prolog which is true if M and N differ more than X

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

First of all I am completely new to prolog and I am trying to write a predicate length(M,X,N) which is true, if M differs from N more than X.

I wrote the following testcase which is true if M(=dec.5) and N(=dec.2) differ more than X(=dec.2). And it is true in this case because 5 and 2 have a difference of 3 which is more than 2:

```
?- length(s(s(s(s(s(0))))), s(s(0)), s(s(0))).
   true .
```

I know that prolog works recursively so I am wondering if I can construct such a predicate with conditions (for example <,>) like in languages like C, or if there is another way to do this in prolog. Sorry for this simple question but I just started with prolog.

Comment: What's all of the `dec.5` and `s(s(0))` stuff? You should read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct predicates for greater or less. For example:

```
greater_than(s(_), 0).
greater_than(s(X), s(Y)) :-
    greater_than(X, Y).
```

And similarly:

```
less_than(0, s(_)).
less_than(s(X), s(Y)) :-
    less_than(X, Y).
```

If you want to find the absolute difference, you could do something like this:

```
abs_diff(0, 0, 0).
abs_diff(s(X), 0, s(X)).
abs_diff(0, s(X), s(X)).
abs_diff(s(X), s(Y), D) :-
    abs_diff(X, Y, D).
```

Those concepts should help kick start some ideas for how to solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: THX your tools helped a lot. That was exactly what I was looking for. I just had to combine.

Comment: do you know a command in prolog where I can force that length(0, 0, 0) results in false. I need (0, 0, 0) to result in false because I found one testcase where my solution did not work.

Comment: @SEPS you just have to make sure your rules and facts don't allow `length(0,0,0)` to succeed. If a query doesn't succeed, it fails.

Comment: @SEPS Sounds like you chose perhaps to use `length(0,0,0).` as a base case which would be incorrect if you don't want that case to succeed. You probably want `length(s(_),0,...)` and/or `length(0,s(_),...)` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

This answer follows up on @lurker's fine answer and improves the determinism of the auxiliary predicate `abs_diff/3` by utilizing 
[first argument clause indexing](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Indexing-Overview.html).

Introducing `x_y_dist/3`:

```
x_y_dist(0, Y, Y).
x_y_dist(s(X), Y, Z) :-
   y_sx_dist(Y, X, Z).

y_sx_dist(0, X, s(X)).
y_sx_dist(s(Y), X, Z) :-
   x_y_dist(X, Y, Z).
```

Sample query:

```
?- x_y_dist(X, Y, s(s(0))).                             % |X-Y| = 2
(  X =           0     , Y =         s(s(0))            % |0-2| = 2
;  X =       s(s(0))   , Y =             0              % |2-0| = 2
;  X =         s(0)    , Y =       s(s(s(0)))           % |1-3| = 2
;  X =     s(s(s(0)))  , Y =           s(0)             % |3-1| = 2
;  X =       s(s(0))   , Y =     s(s(s(s(0))))          % |2-4| = 2
;  X =   s(s(s(s(0)))) , Y =         s(s(0))            % |4-2| = 2
;  X =     s(s(s(0)))  , Y =   s(s(s(s(s(0)))))         % |3-5| = 2
;  X = s(s(s(s(s(0))))), Y =       s(s(s(0)))           % |5-3| = 2
;  X =   s(s(s(s(0)))) , Y = s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))        % |4-6| = 2
;  .........
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
?- length(s(s(s(s(s(0))))), s(s(0)), s(s(0))).

length(s(_),0,0).
length(s(M),s(X),s(N)) :- length(M,X,N).
```

Do keep in mind that Prolog's predicates do not return values - so they don't return `true` or `false`. They either succeed or they don't. The interpreter is just telling you if your program succeeds or not.

Comment: Okay. But this just says that X and N must be equal and M can be anything but it can not be X or N. This has nothing to do with the difference between M and N.

Comment: @SEPS - No, this says that M must be greater than N - or, as you put it "M differs from N more than X". This won't work is M is equal to or less than N.